FabricJS toJSON() - How do i get the actual coordinates of objects?
When inspecting the fabric.canvas.toJSON() output, it looks like the provided positioning information is not enough to figure out the positions of objects.
I have tested with a polygon within a group as below. Note: I'm using a "fabricjs-react" wrapper.


 // polygons = []
    let p = new fabric.fabric.Polygon([{x: 20, y: 30}, {x: 120, y: 30}, {x: 120, y: 80}, {x: 20, y: 80}], {
      stroke: 'black',
      fill: 'green',
      strokeWidth: 1,
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      dirty: true,
    })

    let g = new fabric.fabric.Group([p], {
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      selectable: true,
    })

    polygons.push(g)
    

    polygons.forEach((p: any) => {
      editor?.canvas.add(p)
    })



The output before/after a simple horizontal drag of the polygon (note only group's left changes)
**Before**
Group - top: 29.5
Group - left: **19.5**
Polygon - top: -25.5
Polygon - left: -50.5


**After**
Group - top: 29
Group - left: 34.25
Polygon - top: -25.5
Polygon - left: -50.5


Points of the polygon remain unchanges:
{x: 20, y: 30}
{x: 120, y: 30}
{x: 120, y: 80}
{x: 20, y: 80}

Given the provided information the coordinates of the polygon can not be calculated. There is simply not enough information in the JSON. The polygon's points are neither updated nor computed relatively to the group (which X coord. does update)
Looked through the Gotcha list but can't seem to figure out exactly what should be different or if it's an issue with fabric's toJSON function
